# Monotonicity of ratio of symmetric polynomials

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials, inequalities, symmetric-polynomials

The complete homogeneous symmetric polynomials of degree $\ell$ in $n$ variables are defined by
\begin{equation*}
h_{\ell}(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n) = \sum_{1 \leq i_1 \leq i_2 \leq \ldots \leq i_{\ell} \leq n} x_{i_1} x_{i_2} \ldots x_{i_{\ell}}.
\end{equation*}
With the notation $x^{[k]}$ meaning that $x$ is repeated $k$ times, we define the functions
\begin{equation*}
\Psi_{i,n}(x) = \frac{h_{\ell} \left( 1^{[n-i]},x^{[i]} \right)^2}
{h_{\ell} \left( 1^{[n-i-1]},x^{[i+1]} \right) h_{\ell} \left( 1^{[n-i+1]},x^{[i-1]} \right)}, \quad 
i=2,3,\ldots,n-2; \quad n \geq 4.
\end{equation*}

We conjecture that, for any $\ell \geq 1$, each function $\Psi_{i,n}, i=2,3,\ldots,n-2$, is strictly increasing on the interval $(1,\infty)$?

We have shown that this is true for the function $\Psi_{2,4}$.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev Thanks for the comment. You are right, I should have mentioned that in my question the integer $\ell$ is supposed to be greater than or equal to $1$. I have edited the question accordingly.